# R - extracting a list element by name when the name is in a variable

Tags: r, list

I'm trying to extract a list element by name, when the name is stored in a variable. i.e.:

```
myList <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3) ## list definition
## I can extract the second element like this:
myList$b
## but say I have a variable:
to_extract <- "b"
##can I do something like this?
myList$to_extract
```

Thanks!

Comment: `myList[to_extract]` will get you the full element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should all work.

```
myList[[to_extract]]

`[[`(myList, to_extract)

library(purrr)
pluck(myList, to_extract)
```

Comment: I have a vector of names (character), e.g. `v1=c('a','c')`. `MyList[[v1]]` does not work but `MyList[v1]` does.

Comment: @xm1 Good point. This depends on how many elements you want to extract. `[[`works for single element. `[` works for multiple elements and still make them as a list.